# upload content only when showing

Tags: javascript, video, optimization, displayobject

I have a video is displaying only when i hover a button and so i want to optimize the loading of my page by uploading this video only when i hover my button, how can i set it ?

```js
$('#iso-fire').mouseover(function(){
   $('#bgvid2').show();

  }); 
$('#iso-fire').mouseout(function(){
   $('#bgvid2').hide();
```

```css
video#bgvid2 {
display:none;

}
```

```html
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <video autoplay loop id="bgvid2">
  <source src="video/fire.mov" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "charging" a video?

Comment: upload ( i dont want my video upload when the page is uploading but when i hover on the button)

Comment: Wouldn't you want it to upload in the background, no matter what the user action? What, very broadly, is this page designed to do?

Comment: the goal is to optimize the loading of my page, my video' s size is 3Mo, so for the moment my page stay on the loading screen during 10 secondes or more.... because of this video so I want my page opens and when it' s done i can upload the video